# A random walk on a finite square with prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, random-walk, visualization, pattern-recognition

*This question is following two similar questions that you can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072308/help-with-a-prime-number-spiral-which-turns-90-degrees-at-each-prime) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074824/a-prime-number-random-walk).*

---

> The idea is to walk on a square of length $n\times n$, following some rules. We will identify the opposite sides.

Formally, the square with the opposite sides identified can be modelled by $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^2$.

We will walk following the following rules:

- We start on the bottom left case, facing north. This correspond to the number $k=1$.
- Each time we take a step, we increase $k$ by $1$, and if $k$ happens to be a prime number, we turn $90$ degrees right.

We wall $p(n)$ the smallest number of steps we need to walk on every case of the square.

We will draw the walk for $n=3$ to illustrate the rules, and to be convince that $p(3)=9$:

[image]

I am interested in the sequence $p$.

What I think is true is the following result.

> **Conjecture.** We have $p(n)<\infty \iff (n=2 \text{ or }n\text{ is odd})$.

I have computed the first values of $p(n)$ using SageMath:

$$\begin{matrix} n &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10\\ p(n) &1 &4 &9 &? &90 &? &256 &? &364 &? \end{matrix}$$

I convinced myself that $p(n)=\infty$ if $n$ was an even number greater than $3$ thanks to the following drawing for $n=4$:

[image]

The green circles represent the case that are potentially attainable. The two blue rectangles highlights the fact that only even numbers will be able to go there, which convinced me that some case will not be attainable.

However this is not very formal, so if you know a way to formalise this proof please let me know.

Plus, I don't know how to prove that $p(n)<\infty$ if $n$ is odd. May be this is even false.

If you want to know what $p(n)$ looks like for $n$ odd in $\{1,\ldots, 100\}$,$\{1,\ldots, 200\}$ and $\{1,\ldots, 400\}$ respectively, here are three pictures of the sequence.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> My questions are the following:
>
> - How could I begin to prove (or disprove) the conjecture? Do you have any references?
> - What would be the growth rate of $p$? Can we find an equivalent of $p(2n+1)$? (but that would be too beautiful, so the following question is easier but implied by this)
> - Is there two interesting sequences $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that for all $n$, $\alpha(n)\leqslant p(n)\leqslant \beta(n)$?
> - What else can we say about this sequence?

Comment: This is very exciting!  Looking forwards to the results.

Comment: In regards to your question in how to formalize your argument for the $n$ even case. If instead you consider all possible paths where you can change direction (either left, right or forward) after two steps, it is not hard to prove rigorously that if $n$ is even then you get a "grid" of all possible steps that misses every second block. But the path defined by the primes is contained in such a subset of the grid after you hit $3$. Hence we get $p(n)=\infty$ in this case.

Comment: @LeonSot Thank you for your comment, this is really helpful !

Comment: Did @LeonSot prove your conjecture? It seems like Yes, he did. BTW. In description of your question you said 'square of *length* of $n\times n$'. Is it correct?   P.S. very interesting problem.

Comment: @Wolfgang The proof provided by LeonSot is helpful but does not fully prove the conjecture since it only proves $p(2k)=\infty$ but not $p(2k+1)<\infty$.

Comment: @Wolfgang And yes *square of length $n\times n$* is correct. When I say that I mean "$n$ by $n$ cases", I don't know if it's more clear that way.

Comment: Sorry for useless question but how long your algorithm (which calculates $p(n)$) works for 100 squares. Now I am trying to get points in order to analyze behavior of $p(n)$. But my algorithm is too slow. 25 points took 8 mins.

Comment: I only provided a proof for the $n=2k$ case. It seems to me that the full conjecture implies something non trivial about the gaps between primes, so I think a proof for the full conjecture will be difficult. At least far beyond my grasp of number theory.

Comment: Although saying that, there is a probabilistic reason on why the conjecture should be true. If at each second step $2k$ the probability for the walk to turn right is $\frac{\pi(2k)}{2k}$, then as each block is attainable when $n$ odd, I'm fairly sure there is a rigorous argument that the walk will eventually reach each block with probability $1$.

Comment: @Wolfgang For a square $25\times 25$ it takes less than a second. I am using SageMath. Would you like me to post my algorithm ?

Comment: @LeonSot Yes, the probabilistic reason motivated this conjecture. Though I hope someone will provide a rigorous argument.

Comment: @E.Joseph  Could you?

Comment: @E.Joseph  No, you should not. I found the way to optimize mine.

Comment: @Wolfgang Great news ! :) (I was about to post mine) Let me know if you change your mind.

Comment: Snag was a difference between `prime_range` and `is_prime()` methods in sage.

Comment: @E.Joseph Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems to appear some faint oscillatory pattern? I'd love to see the power vs frequency plot of the data series and check it is far from being noisy.

Comment: @CarlosToscano-Ochoa I don't really know how to do that, but feel free to do so and to post it as an answer if you try it!

Comment: Roughly eyeballing it, $p(n)$ looks like it grows in the neighborhood of $2x^2log(n)$. It would be interesting to overlay a few such graphs (for example $2x^2log(n), 2.2x^2log(n), 2x^2(log(n) + log(log(n))$) on top of your graphs.

Comment: @E. Joseph I believe that an answer to your conjecture will be that its true, and a good approach in my opinion will be Green-Tao theorem for polynomial progressions.

Answer (score 3):

your conjecture is True assuming that : there is a $k$ sequence of consecutive primes that the difference between every two consecutive prime of that sequence produces the sequence $\{n-1,n-1,n-1,n-2,n-2,n-3,n-3,.....,2,2,1,1\} \mod n$ such that $n-1$ element is repeated $3$ time and all the other elements are repeated $2$ times in descending order.

which is $2n-1$ elements or $2n$ consecutive prime.

to explain what i mean, lets take $n=3$ so i am looking for $2*3= 6$ consecutive prime numbers that their consecutive difference produces $\{2,2,2,1,1\} \mod 3$

now if i assume that this will happen for all odd $n$ numbers, then no matter at what cell in the square i was standing or in what direction i was going, i am guaranteed to travel across every cell in the $n*n$ square.

note : as i wrote in the comments, i think that the assumption could be proved by Green-Tao theorem (i am not sure of that).

i hope this give you some idea on how to tackle this problem